# ggplot Interactive tool tips on map without plotly

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I am trying to plot data on a US map by state in R. I want to add interactive tool tips to my maps but my organization’s R build doesn’t support plotly. Does anyone have suggestions on alternatives?

I thought of googlevis but that requires an internet connection to operate. I prefer solutions that do not require active internet connection to work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you checked http://jkunst.com/highcharter/ yet?

Comment: I have not previously but this looks promising. Thank you!

Comment: [library(mapview)](https://github.com/r-spatial/mapview) is tight too

Comment: See also `leaflet` & `leaflet-offline` https://github.com/robertomlsoares/leaflet-offline

Comment: Thank you for your inputs! I’ve followed a few of them and ended up on this page https://www.htmlwidgets.org/showcase_leaflet.html

Comment: Thank you for your inputs! I followed some of your solutions and ended up on this page -> https://www.htmlwidgets.org/showcase_leaflet.html . It has a good list of packages to explore. Thank you again for your responses!